# mouseover and mouseout events over svg.circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Implementation idea is tooltip to be shown when we hover over the svg circle element on d3 graph. When I hover over circle, radius of that circle expands from 1 to 5. Problem I am trying to solve is that when I hover circle which is inside radius(exapnded from 1 to 5)of current hovered circle it won't be shown, because mouse never leaves current circle. Any idea of a workaround here? 
Code:

```
svg.selectAll("dot")
                .data(serverData)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr('opacity',1)
                .attr("r", 1)
                .attr("stroke-width",2)
                .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                    // this.setAttribute('opacity',1)
                    this.setAttribute('r',5);
                    console.log("datum trenutnog kruga: "+moment(d.calc_month).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
                    return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible").html("<span class='pull-left' >medijan:"+Math.round(d.median*100)/100+"</span>"+
                        "<br/><span class='pull-left' >datum: "+moment(d.calc_month).format('YYYY-MM-DD')+"</span>");
                })

                // we move tooltip during of "mousemove"

                .on("mousemove", function(event) {
                    return tooltip.style("top", (event.pageY - 30) + "px")
                        .style("left", event.pageX + "px");
                })

                // we hide our tooltip on "mouseout"

                .on("mouseout", function() {
                    this.setAttribute('r',1);
                    return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");
                });
```

[image]

Comment: On what browsers?

Comment: I am trying with chrome

Comment: Try Firefox. I suspect this is a Chrome bug.

Comment: Can you provide the complete code snippet which you are working on so that it'll be more easier to debug

Comment: @RoopashreeR I think rest of code is irrelevant for this specific problem . I put picture on edited post to give you better insight of what I am talking about. When I am inside expanded circle I can't access the other circle which is inside boundings of expanded one